# Weird issue with rails link_to button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails link I'm trying to add into a dropdown and it is acting weird and I can't figure out why.

I have pasted the code block below:

```
<%= link_to edit_profile_post_path(article.profile, article.post), :class => "dropdown-item" if article.post.present? do %>
   <div class="flex">
      <div class="w-5 mr-2 flex items-center justify-center">
         <i class="text-inherit fal icon-sm fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    Edit Post
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I preview the dropdown I see the link path instead of the words "Edit Post":

[image]

Buts what stumps me even more is that when I hover over the link, it is actually:

http://localhost:3000/profiles/gerard-donnelly?class=dropdown-item

The original code that works fine is:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_profile_post_path(article.profile, article.post), class: 'dropdown-item' if article.post.present? %>
```

Would really appreciate any help on fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the condition on the wrong side of the call. If it was pure ruby, this would look like

```rb
link_to(path, class: 'klass') if article.post.present? do
  'content'
end
```

The `do/end` block is passed to the `present?` method, which is not what you want. Instead:

```rb
link_to(path, class: 'klass') do
  'content'
end if article.post.present?
```

will work. Translating back to ERB:

```
<%= link_to edit_profile_post_path(article.profile, article.post), :class => "dropdown-item" do %>
   <div class="flex">
      <div class="w-5 mr-2 flex items-center justify-center">
         <i class="text-inherit fal icon-sm fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    Edit Post
  </div>
<% end if article.post.present? %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this method. It worked perfectly. I had solved it a few minutes ago by removing the the if statement and wrapping the entire link to in a separate if block. This way is a lot cleaner. Cheers